# How do i solve the include path error in vs code?

Tags: c

I am using macOS Big Sur.
First I got include path error for `#include <stdio.h>`.
I don't remember/know how it got resolved and now I'm getting error for `#include <conio.h>` but not for `<stdio.h>`.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
int a;
int b;
scanf("%d%d", &a , &b) ;
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
fatal error: 'conio.h' file not found
#include <conio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I've tried configuring the compiler path, but the error is still not resolved.

Comment: `conio.h` is a MS-DOS header file and probably does not exist / is not relevant on the Mac.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h#:~:text=h%20is%20a%20C%20header,and%20output%22%20from%20a%20program.

Comment: The include `<conio.h>` is an old Windows-only header. Just don't use it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not tag both C and C++ unless you really want to use both together or want to know about difference. In all other cases please only add the language that is related to your question as they are very different languages.

Answer (score 2):

`<conio.h>` is a MS-DOS header file and Turbo C++ (TCC) is obsolete. Stop using it. The codes written on TCC are not compatible on most modern C++ compilers.so, dont use `<conio.h>` header file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a;
int b;
scanf("%d%d", &a , &b) ;
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) says:

> `<conio.h>` "is a C header file, used mostly by MS-DOS compilers. It
> is not part of the C standard library or ISO C, nor it is defined from
> POSIT

So, because Mac is not based on MS-DOS, the library isn't C standard, and there's no maintaining for compatibility between operating systems, your machine will not know what `<conio.h>` is. You should use the standard `<stdio.h>` in C or `<iostream>` in C++.

using standard C `<stdio.h>` (`printf()` and `scanf()`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int a;
    int b;

    scanf("%d%d", &a , &b);
    printf("%d%d", a , b);

    return 0;
}
```

Using standard C++ `<iostream>` (using `std::cin` and `std::cout`)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std; is bad

int main()
{
    int a{};
    int b{};

    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << b;

    return 0;
}
```